# Call the latest posts from a custom field group to be displayed on front-page

Tags: custom-field, metabox

i have this custom Metabox field group from https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#group containing 3 fields and displayed on the Products page template, i want to call the latest posts the client add to display them on my front-page. here is the code of the custom fields.

```js
/**
     * Repeatable Field Groups
     */
    $meta_boxes['field_group'] = array(
        'id'           => 'field_group',
        'title'        => __( 'Manage your products here', 'cmb2' ),
        'show_on'      => array( 'id' => array( 11, ) ), // Specific post IDs to display this metabox
        'object_types' => array( 'page', ),
        'fields'       => array(
            array(
                'id'          => $prefix . 'repeat_group',
                'type'        => 'group',
                'options'     => array(
                    'group_title'   => __( 'Product {#}', 'cmb2' ), // {#} gets replaced by row number
                    'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Product', 'cmb2' ),
                    'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Product', 'cmb2' ),
                    'sortable'      => true, // beta
                ),
                'fields'      => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Product Name',
                        'id'   => 'product_name',
                        'type' => 'text',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Product Description',
                        'description' => 'Write a short description for this Product',
                        'id'   => 'product_description',
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Product Image',
                        'id'   => 'product_image',
                        'type' => 'file',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

UPDATE:
i found this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts but i still can't figure out how to make it get the posts from the custom fields

Comment: Is your product pages are displaying all these 3 fields correctly? You want to show 3 latest products on homepage right?

Comment: yeah products page works just fine all the field's values displayed fine , like you said i just want to call the latest 6 entries on my homepage , the html markup would be 3x2 grid if you must know so i need the values displayed on this markup to be the latest entries from the products page

Comment: Do you understand that this group adds custom fields so there is no such thing like latest in this. You can either get first few or last few.

Comment: if i understand you well , calling the last few will do the trick for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you can paste this on your front page template.
I assumed that your `$prefix` is `prefix` and products page id is `11` and you want to print last `3` entries.

```
<?php $meta_entries_pre = get_post_meta( 11, 'prefix_repeat_group', true ); $meta_entries_int = array_reverse( $meta_entries_pre ); $meta_entries = array_slice( $meta_entries_int, 0, 3 ); if( ! empty( $meta_entries ) ) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( (array) $meta_entries as $key => $entry ) {
            $product_name = $product_description = $meta_link = '';
            if ( isset( $entry['product_name'] ) ) $product_name = $entry['product_name'];
            if ( isset( $entry['product_description'] ) ) $product_description = $entry['product_description'];
            if ( isset( $entry['product_image'] ) ) $product_image = esc_html( $entry['product_image'] ); ?>
                <li>
                    <h3><?php echo $product_name; ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $product_description; ?></p>
                    <p><img src="<?php echo $product_image; ?>" alt="" /></p>
                </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```